# Sockets in Java Master-Slave

Tags: java, sockets

i need help about sockets in java...

I have to develop a routine where I create a master ServerSocket that will control a list of numbers and other slave machines can connect to go testing each number from the list and tell if it is prime or not ...

I created a helper class that has the properties Number, State (Tested, Waiting and NotTested) and IsPrimo

I also created a static list helper class that contains numbers which will test

thus each slave would ask for the master and test whether a number is prime returning to the master and the master would update the list until all values ​​would keep the state .... Tested

as I have little knowledge with sockets in java, I'm really struggling to know how to implement this exchange of information ..

needs to be asynchronously

can anyone help me or give me an example implemented like? apparently is not difficult but as I said I have little knowledge about it.

sorry about english!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server should run a loop.  The loop should:

- Get a Socket from the ServerSocket
- Determine whether the client is requesting a number or reporting completion on a number
- If the client is requesting a number, get a number that is NotTested and give it to the client, changing the number's state to Waiting
- If the client is reporting completion on a number, change the number's state to Tested